# cookie_httponly and flash?

Tags: php, flash, cookie-httponly

Will it be a problem for flash if I set the `cookie_httponly` option in PHP?

Does Flash still send POST requests to with the session?

I know that is something you can easily try but I don't know much about Flash and I am worried I might break something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think that was a stupid question.

`cookie_httponly` does change the browsers behavior and should not affect Flash in any way. The session id will still be transmitted in the http header.